# how create an image with half curved shape?

Tags: android, android-imageview, shapes

I want to create an image like this

[image]

how can I achieve it?

Comment: That looks like a custom ImageView, which uses `Rect` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this one
    <developer.shivam.crescento.CrescentoImageView
        android:id="@+id/crescentoImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bike_wallpaper"
        app:crescentoTintMode="manual"
        app:curvature="50dp"
        android:rotation="90"
        app:curvatureDirection="outward"
       />
```

Check this URL
https://github.com/developer-shivam/crescento?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4684

Comment: yes thank you but i have problem in it i have white space in right how i delete it ?

Comment: @SabrenasSweet you import the library as a module. then you can edit the library since it is a module.